# How do I make a new git pull request when an earlier revert commit keeps deleting my files?

Tags: git, git-revert, git-fork

I have a branch on my fork

```
"master" on tpc/projecthame
src/code.go
```

and a team repo

```
"master" on team/projectname
```

I created a pull request on "team" and got src/code.go into team/projectname

Then many more commits were made and then my commit it team/projectname was reverted. This means not only is src/code.go gone, there is a record that in order to merge from here, src/code.go is to be deleted. Fair enough.

Now I need to try again to make a pull request. I start by trying to pull in all those commits into my tpc/projectname fork. I usually do something like this.

Update my fork:

```
git checkout master
```

Merge in the changes my teammates made:

```
git pull upstream master
```

Then

```
push origin
```

but that pesky revert sees src/code.go and deletes it on me. What I want is for it to think that I'm adding the same files again and keep all the change history.

I tried dozens of variations of rebase and merge and checking out versions on branches and so far I always end up with all my files removed.  I could just update with all the files deleted, and then re-add them, but that would lose all the history, not to mention I'd look like I don't know what I'm doing.

I can see all the commit SHA identifiers, and I suspect they will play a role.

This ought to be an everyday thing in "git", right? Nobody out there had to do over a pull request to a remote fork because something got reverted? I don't understand why this isn't part of ever tutorial out there.

Comment: I'm confused.  If you're creating a pull request on the `master` branch, then what is the target branch?  It doesn't make sense to have a PR from master to master, right?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think OP is creating a pull request from a fork. So it could be a pull request from his forked repo `origin master` to `upstream master`.

Comment: Both branches are named master, one on tpc/projectname (origin) and the other on team/projectname. (upstream)  (Maybe I should have used a branch on tpc/projectname?) On the first checkout it assumes origin.

Comment: What do you mean by "pull request from my fork to the team repo was reverted"? What actually happened?

Comment: The PR into team/projectname from tpc/projectname had a failing Jenkins test, but they merged it anyways and later changed their minds and reverted it. I need to get it back to a failing Jenkins test in a new PR before I can fix it. If I try and make the PR from tpc/projectname, git claims there are no changes and refuses. If I try and merge the team/projectname into my fork and then replay my files on top, git refuses because it thinks I'm trying to delete them. (Sorry, if I knew enough to answer clearly I would probably have the answer.)